# Fitting a whole row of a MySQL table onto a single JLabel in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jlabel

I have Java code the successfully connects Java to MySQL.

I have two classes. One that creates the GUI with Java and another class that specifically gets information from MySQL.

I'm trying to find a good way to put a whole row of information as a String into each JLabel on MyGUI.

Here is my code in each class (excluding connecting to the database):

### CLASS 1

String result = "";

contactsList()
    {

```
    //extra classes
    db=new database();

    result = db.getContact();
```

### label1 =new JLabel(result);

### CLASS 2

PreparedStatement pst, pst2;
    ResultSet rs, rs2;

pst2 = con.prepareStatement("select LastName, FirstName from contacts");

```
public String getContact()
{
  String result2 = "";
   try {
  rs2=pst2.executeQuery();

  while (rs2.next())
  {
        result2 = rs2.getString(1);
  }



  return result2;
   }

 catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("error while validating"+e);
        return "";
    }
```

### }

Right now the rows in my Contacts table in MySQL has columns separated by commas

1, Rivera, Angelo, 2890 something st. ventura 93003, Null

2, Person, Random, 1223 I dunno ave. Camairllo 93001, 423-123-5313

Right now when I try to put a whole row in the "label1" the only text it shows is "Person".

How do I make it so it shows the whole Row in the JLabel?

Also how would I format the code so I can call the the function to get the next row of information and put it into another label?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are only asking it to retrieve one column from your result set by the looks of things :

```
result2 = rs2.getString(1);
```

If you want to display more data, you just need to retrieve it and format it somehow :

```
result2 = rs2.getString(1) + " : " + rs2.getString(2);
```

for example.

But there are other problems with the select statement I think.

```
select LastName, FirstName from contacts
```

will retrieve the LastName and FirstName from every row in the database. The way your loop construct works means that `result2` will contain the data for the last row in the table only. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a JTable for this. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.

Then you might want to check out [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/). The `Table From Database Example` code may be the easiest way to start.